# Can't load a URL form a popover in a webview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a favorites popover and a webView. When you select a cell in the tableview of the popover, the webview should load that URL, but I get a SIGABRT or a BAD_ACCESS.

Here's some code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (tableView == favoritesTable1) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        textField.text = cell.textLabel.text;
        [web loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:cell.textLabel.text]]];
        [cell release];
        [favoritesTable1 reloadData];
    }
}
```

I want to get something like this but full working:

[image: example image]

PS: The popover is a new viewController from the same class where the webview is set.

Comment: Now where exactly does the `web` var come from?

Comment: Please show us some more code and the error log.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't `retain` the cell, you shouldn't `release` it... that's almost assuredly where your crash is coming from.

Also, you're leaking some memory by using alloc/init without autorelease. Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView == favoritesTable1) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        textField.text = cell.textLabel.text;
        [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cell.textLabel.text]]];
        [favoritesTable1 reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize both NSURLRequest & NSURL with alloc init, which both return retained objects make sure you initialize them properly according the rules for Memory Management. Also I see you release the cell - you don't have to because you don't own it. Try this way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (tableView == favoritesTable1) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        textField.text = cell.textLabel.text;
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:cell.textLabel.text];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [web loadRequest:request];
        [url release];
        [request release];
        [favoritesTable1 reloadData];
    }
}
```

What is the web var? It could cause problems also.

Comment: Did the solution fixed the problem? If not show some code how you initialize the UIWebView.